# CakePHP & Twitter Bootstrap CSS button icons

Tags: html, css, cakephp

I have this code;

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), 
            array('action' => 'delete', $homepage['Homepage']['ContentID']),
            array('class'=>'btn icon-plus'),
            __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $homepage['Homepage']['ContentID'])); ?>
```

Where it displays the text 'Delete' I would like to put the trashcan icon from the twitter bootstrap css package. However when I do;

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('<i class="icon-trash"></i>')....
```

It only displays the html rather than grabbing the icon.

Can anyone explain why its doing this and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `'escape' => false` option to the third param.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), 
            array('action' => 'delete', $homepage['Homepage']['ContentID']),
            array('class'=>'btn icon-plus', 'escape' => false),
            __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $homepage['Homepage']['ContentID'])); ?>
```

Comment: +1 after struggling for an hour, got to this solution and it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the path to the "glyphicons-halflings.png" file is correct. By default, this image should be located in a directory named "img" that is at the same level as the folder containing the bootstrap.css file (named "css" in the default download).

```
css/bootstrap.css
img/glyphicons-halflings.png
```

Check your error console to see if there are any requested files not found.