# CakePHP & Twitter Bootstrap: CSS icons in a button

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to insert a icon of Twitter Bootstrap into this specific button.

The previous mentioned method to add `'escape' => false` (here: [CakePHP & Twitter Bootstrap CSS button icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004567/cakephp-twitter-bootstrap-css-button-icons)) does not work for me.

I tested it succesfully with a simple html-bootstrap-code - but with cakePHP-specific code it does not work.

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(__('set User'), 
array('controller' => 'institutions', 'action' => 'setAssignee', $user['User']    ['institution_id'], $user['User']['id']), 
array('class' => 'btn btn-warning icon-plus'), 
__('Are you sure?', $user['User']['last_name'], $institution['Institution']['name']));
```

Comment: "it does not work" - please clarify

Comment: no icon is showing up, the button itself is very small (smaller than the text in it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't work, the `icon-plus` class will be overridden by the background applied to `btn`.

To get this to work, use an `<i>` like this:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('<i class="icon-plus"></i> ' . __('set User'), 
array('controller' => 'institutions', 'action' => 'setAssignee', $user['User']    ['institution_id'], $user['User']['id']), 
array('class' => 'btn btn-warning', 'escape'=>false), 
__('Are you sure?', $user['User']['last_name'], $institution['Institution']['name']));
```

Comment: thanks, and be sure that you don't have any apostrophs left in your dialog: With this text (`Are you sure "someVariable"`) the form will be closed before its posted. Put `&quot;` instead.